# Velocity.js with jQuery using pre-defined functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

Velocity.js provides example like these that work with jQuery:

```
$element
    .velocity("slideDown", { duration: 1500 })
    .velocity("slideUp", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
```

However I want to use vanilla Javascript like so:

```
Velocity(document.getElementById("dummy"), { opacity: 0.5 }, { duration: 1000 });
```

This works fine but I would like the use the pre-defined `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions here.

How would I go about using those given my vanilla Javascript example?

Comment: `slideUp` and `slideDown` are jQuery's.

Comment: sadly thats not possible without jquery you could program your own function though

Comment: Ugh, I wish people wouldn't comment when they don't know anything about VelocityJS...

Comment: @Rycochet true, I've already found out that these functions from jQuery have been put into Velocity.js so they work out-of-the-box. Unlike what people are saying here.

Comment: @Stephan-v yeah - they've been in for several years, and the quickest of google searches will show that :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you include `velocity-ui.js`, and use them exactly he same way as before -

```
Velocity(document.getElementById("dummy"), "slideDown", { duration: 1000 });
```

The jQuery helper function simply pulls the element list out of the first argument - don't forget you can pass the result from any element finding method including `document.querySelectorAll` (or even jQuery if you wanted to) as that first argument.